# Razor MVC3 Routing/Navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, navigation, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to wrap my head around the routing that comes with MVC3.  I am using Razor to code my site.  I am wondering what the best practice is to setup the following scenario in a dynamic routing-based method.

Currently my site structure is setup as follows (where CAPS are folders):

```
- Default.cshtml
- About.cshtml
- Contact.cshtml
- Services.cshtml
- CONTENT
  - ABOUT
     - aboutus.cshtml
     - history.cshtml
  - CONTACT
     - contact1.cshtml
     - contact2.cshtml
  - SERVICES
     - service-web.cshtml
     - service-mobile.cshtml
     - all.cshtml
- VIEWS
- CONTROLLERS
- MODELS
```

Currently the urls display as such:

```
www.website.com/content/about/aboutus.cshtml
www.website.com/content/contact/contact2.cshtml
www.website.com/content/services/all.cshtml
```

So I would PREFER my urls to look like this:

```
www.website.com/about/aboutus
www.website.com/contact/contact2
www.website.com/services/all
```

So how in the name of everything holy is this possible? I have been looking around here for quite some time and everything I find is relating to date or ID based urls - rather than folders like my site is.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to learn more about MVC 3 :
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/09/free-video-training-asp-net-mvc-3-features.aspx

Comment: Ok yes I am sure I do. :)  However can you tell me at least where and how I should keep my content pages organized once I DO have the mvc structured properly?   Almost everything I have seen is DB powered, or just 2 pages.  My site will be about 100 static pages.

Comment: And my other question then -- Should I be starting off with a New Project in VS2011?  Last time I chose a New Website and it seemed to be missing many of the necessary references and such.

Comment: Visual studio 2010 is enough. VS 2011 is still in a beta version.